# Does loading external scripts async on page increases latency in page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am including **external JavaScript files Facebook and CrazyEgg in async mode**.

So my question is: does these script could increase latency to execute ready function of jQuery .

**I am including external JS files in bottom of layout:**

```
  setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
  var b=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  a.src=document.location.protocol+"//dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/0012/6522.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
  a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);

  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({appId: "facebook_app_id", status: true, cookie: true});
  };
  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
```

---

So above external JS could cause any latency to execute `my_function();` ?

`myapp_js_file.js` is included in head of layout

```
// myapp_js_file.js

$(document).ready(function() {
  my_function();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge calling anything (especially externals) will increase latency as more requests are required to complete.

I dont know however if rails caches anything like this, though I doubt it.

The increased latency (if any) should be nominal however

Comment: thanks to put your view on this, but as we are loading external js files in async mode, even then would it cause latency?

Comment: AFAIK more requests = more time

Comment: The latency increase would be nominal however